# Referencing php in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, flot

I am trying to call a php code which retrieves data from mysql table and populate it to an array and accessing it in the javascript. But screen shows nothing I know for sure there is no problem with php in populating the data, and referencing the php variable in javascript I have included the file and the file is in my Eclipse (juno) project only. But still why I get this problem?

Any suggestions please?

**sample.jsp**:

```
<div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function () {
include("db.php");
var dataset1 = "<?php echo json_encode($dataset1); ?>";
$.plot($("#placeholder"), [ dataset1 ]);
});
```

**db.php**:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/javascript'); 
$server = "localhost";
    $user="harish";
    $password="password";  
    $database = "db";
    $connection = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
    $db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection);
    $query = "SELECT xval,yval FROM flottable";
    $result = mysql_query($query);        
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $dataset1[] = array($row['xval'],$row['yval']);
    }
?>
```

Reference: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/externalphp.shtml

I also googled and found out that if I add this to an `.htaccess` file it would work. I tried this as well but nothing works.

Any idea what the problem is?

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .js
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .js
<FilesMatch "\.(js|php)$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: use a browser console to look at errors...would have seen a few and at least give you a start point to debugging

Answer (score 1):

Seems you forgot to set include("db.php"); between php opening brackets.

```
<?php include("db.php");?>
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Your `include()` command should be in `<?php ... ?>` tags, and with `json_encode` you don't need quotes around it (in fact using quotes will severely break your JavaScript). Correct these two errors and your code should work.

Comment: Thanks tried but dont know whats the problem even then doesnt works :(

Comment: John  & Kolink thanks for ur suggestions but both doesnt seem to work like it not at all recognizing the php inside js i guess.if i comment the  php include and double qoute the json_encode line i get the graph without any ploting just the backside mesh.