# How can I pass a php include call as a variable for javascript function?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a page that use javascript innerhtml to replace the contents of an element as a pseudo-static page.

The following code is from the current content of that element:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('***********', '******', '**********');
mysql_select_db(dbbmdmi);

if ($con) {
    $sql = "SELECT TeamID, Captain, CountryID, ArrDate, DepDate FROM Teams";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    $link = "<a id='" . $row["TeamID"] . "' onClick='SetTeamID();ReplaceContentInContainer('content','replace_target6')'>Edit</a>";

    if ($result) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            echo "Captain: " . $row["Captain"]. "<a id='" . $row["TeamID"] . "' onClick=\"ReplaceContentInContainer2('content','<?php include 'scripts/editteam.php?TeamID=" . $row["TeamID"] . "'>')\">Edit</a>;" . "</br>Country: " . $row["CountryID"]. "</br>Dates: " . $row["ArrDate"]. " - ". $row["DepDate"]. "<br>";
        }
?>
```

In `onClick=\"ReplaceContentInContainer2('content','<?php include 'scripts/editteam.php?TeamID=" . $row["TeamID"] . "'>')` I'm trying to pass the php include as the "source" argument to the following function in the original "container" page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ReplaceContentInContainer2(target,source) {
        document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = source;
    }
</script>
```

I keep getting this error when I click the link:

> teams.php:1SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'scripts'. Expected ')' to end a argument list.

Basically, I'm trying to pass the `$row_["TeamID"] to the next page in the address so that I can call with a`$_GET` function.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

After escaping the single quotes in the javascript function call, the content of the element is replaced as it should be, except the php include is being rendered in the new content as an html comment, rather than run as php.

escaped single quotes in `onClick=\"ReplaceContentInContainer2('content','<?php include \'scripts/editteam.php?TeamID=" . $row["TeamID"] . "\'?>')\"`

rendered html: `<!--?php include 'scripts/editteam.php?TeamID=Kellog'?-->`

Comment: it will not work like that! What content do you expect to be return from `scripts/editteam.php` ?

Comment: Use AJAX: PHP is evaluated on the server side and therefore JS can never access the team ID value. What does the include aim to do? You can use an AJAX call and retrieve the team IDs dynamically.

Comment: RamRaider - that file will be the new content of the element that replaces the current content.  The idea is to be able to pass the variable to call in the new content.

Comment: An answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908786/javascript-variable-within-a-php-variable/34909191#34909191

Comment: Terry - the javascript doesn't have to access the team ID value, because the PHP renders it as text in the current document in the <a onclick /a> tag.  The javascript shouldn't fire until the php has retrieved the team ID value.  The include calls the php file scripts/editteam.php file to replace the content of the current element.  I agree AJAX would probably be the smarter route, but this should be working.

Comment: FYI, this is what is rendered in the source of the page:  <a id="Kellog" onclick="ReplaceContentInContainer2('content','<?php include 'scripts/editteam.php?TeamID=Kellog'>')">Edit</a>

Comment: so many issues. 1 nested `<?php` tags is a syntax error, you only missed this because you have the nested tag inside quotes, so its just treated as a string. 2 `include` doesnt return anything, 3 `include` takes a filepath, not a url, so no url parameters. 4 if you got around the previous points, dumping a whole wad of html into a js string declaration will fail unless you escape any quotes and remove linebreaks. **tldr;** google: ajax, and promise not to abuse php<>js like this again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referencing php in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215286/referencing-php-in-javascript)

Comment: HorusKol - not referencing php from javascript, rather the html that the php has already rendered.

Comment: Steve - you made an interesting point that made me think.  Because the page is never refreshing, only the content of an element, I can't use a URL anyway.  The include is used elsewhere in the page as the innerhtml to load the new content from a similar javascript function.  Because the page never refreshes, shouldn't I be able to simply set a variable that the new content can reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a very interesting idea. The problem that you're going to run into is that the PHP is just going to render a string of your `<?php include... ?>` because PHP only handles in it initially and then hands it off. Here is probably what you'll want to do.

```
<!-- front-end.html-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function ReplaceContentInContainer2(target,source) {
    document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = source;
}
function ajaxForHtml(url, callback) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      callback(xhttp.responseText); 
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function clickAction(id) {
  ajaxForHtml('scripts/editteam.php?TeamID=' + id, function(data) {
    ReplaceContentInContainer2('content', data);
  });
}
</script>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('***********', '******', '**********');
mysql_select_db(dbbmdmi);

if ($con) {
    $sql = "SELECT TeamID, Captain, CountryID, ArrDate, DepDate FROM Teams";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    $link = "<a id='" . $row["TeamID"] . "' onClick='SetTeamID();ReplaceContentInContainer('content','replace_target6')'>Edit</a>";

    if ($result) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
          echo sprintf('Captain: %s <a id="%d" onclick="clickAction(%d);">Edit</a>;</br>Country: %d</br>Dates: %s - %s </br>',
                        $row['Captain'], $row['TeamId'], $row['TeamId'], $row["CountryID"], $row["ArrDate"], $row["DepDate"]
               );
         }
```

Comment: Iwnnay - thank you for this, unfortunately I have no experience with AJAX (I know, I know, next on my list after mysqli).  Am I calling one of these functions in my <a onclick /a> instead of calling the javascript?

Comment: Onclick is javascript... I'll add the other part in. I got called away.

Comment: I think we may have run into a problem.  In an earlier comment, someone said something that made me think.  This isn't a url link, but rather a file path that is being included through php.  The page is never refreshing, only the content of an element, so doesn't that mean that we can't pass the variable through as in a url?

Comment: You have access to the variable. You can hand that off the JavaScript an that will make the URL call. Maybe this is a lot to go over all at once. There are plenty of great resources for [ajax calls](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/), [html and php](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php) and then finally if you're see yourself doing a lot of front end development there is a great [course for using the dev tools](http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/)

Comment: Anways, take a moment to digest what's up above. I hope it's helpful. It's practically an end to end solution for your issue. This kind of question gets asked a lot on Stack Overflow, so it may be beneficial to just poke around. I have to step away for the evening. Good luck.